# Easy way to toggle some settings on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, settings

If you jailbreak iOS, there is an app that gives you quick access to toggle settings such as wifi, 3g, data, location... by just swiping the top bar.

Is there a similar solution without jailbreaking? an app or a setting?

I have iPhone 4S, iOS5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not because there is no public API making these settings available to developers.

Comment: But there are several URL schemes to get these things done even if they aren't called out in the documentation formally.

Answer (score 3):

Yes if you run iOS 5.0 and not upgrading to iOS 5.1.

For the majority of us, this means no since OS older than 5.0 don't have this and it was disabled at 5.1 and later. Who knows what the future may bring...

---

For historical purposes, here is how this worked on 5.0:

Apple apparently has silently added URL shortcuts for these sort of quick functions to iOS 5.0. [Jeff Broderick](https://twitter.com/#!/brdrck) (blog at http://brdrck.me/ ) has assembled a nice dashboard of these shortcuts with gorgeous icons to save the web clips to the home screen of your iOS device.

Simply browse your iOS device to http://brdrck.me/settings/ and pick from the many web clips that he has assembled. These are basically the same as taking a web site in the iPhone configuration utility and adding it to your home screen with a nice icon.

This could be something that was meant for testing or will get pulled according to some rumors about the latest 5.1 beta - but there's no way to know what will happen other than waiting until official documentation comes out or this change gets pulled / disabled.

Comment: The site has been taken down :-( "Since releasing my settings shortcuts Apple has removed the ability to use this feature. Due to many confused emails from people, I have decided to take the shortcut site down."

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create a webclip that takes me directly to the Call Forwarding toggle screen, something that no one else apparently has done before, which is baffling to me. Anyway, it works great, but I would love to be able to make it toggle the setting on or off. If that's not possible then I could make two that have a static setting of on and off. Anyone know how to do this?

The url for the webclip is: prefs:root=Phone&path=CallForwarding

I created a config profile in iPhoneConfigurationUtility, emailed it to myself, clicked and installed it, and it worked! Simple things like this make me happy.

Comment: Doesn't work since iOS 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Found one at least - search for "Dimmer," gives you brightness. You can set it that each launch toggles between two manual presets. Would be great if it self-quit, but it's better than nothing.

Would be even better if there were equivalent apps for bluetooth, wifi, airplane mode, ringer volume...

Comment: that's interesting. Unfortunately brightness doesn't interest me much, but the concept seems better than nothing. I wrote a feedback to apple (http://www.apple.com/feedback/). Maybe if many of us tell them, they'll care?